# Milliseconds in CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate and SystemModStamp

Tags: apex, soql

**Problem:**

I want to backup salesforce data into local database for history tracking/backup. So I store the SystemModStamp of last fetched record. In my org in a split second so many records gets created. Now I am storing the SystemModStamp of the last record that I pull.
In next pull, I apply the filter as

PULL ALL THE SF RECORDS WHERE SystemModStamp > STORED_LAST_PULL_SYSTEM_MOD_STAMP

Now lets say, my program got interrupted because of some technical reason and I was able to pull 200 records of 500 records which got created at that exact second. If I run my program again then based on above logic I could loose 300 records.

**Questions:**

1. This problem could be minimized to very greater level if somehow, I start getting milliseconds factor in SystemModStamp, so is there any way to get that in salesforce?

See below, whenever I pull records, I don't see any factor in milliseconds part of DateTime fields.
[image]

2. What could be other approach that I could take to perform such activity without loosing any data?

> Note: 
>       I want to sync (create history in backup database ) as SystemModStamp changes when record gets updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22532/how-can-updated-sobjects-cobject-be-queried-retrieved-without-duplicate-or-missi?rq=1 ?

Comment: @Aidan While that question might seem to apply and would be helpful, it was asked in the context of `LastModifiedDate`, not in the context of the `SystemModStamp`. The `SystemModStamp` includes updates initiated by system activity. I  don't know if it is applied before or after the commit.

Comment: @Aidan Thank you for navigating to the right question,  my google search keys were not able to get me to that question :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This problem could be minimized to very greater level if somehow, I start getting milliseconds factor in SystemModStamp, so is there any way to get that in salesforce?

To factor miliseconds

Refer [Capture 'Last Modified' Date including milliseconds](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181547&type=1)

Create a workflow rule which evaluates on create and all edits, with a Field Update to populate a text field using syntax like:

```
LEFT(text(now()),19)+ 
MID(TEXT ( ROUND ( MOD ( ( NOW()- $System.OriginDateTime ) * 86400 , 1), 3) ),2,4)
```

> What could be other approach that I could take to perform such activity without loosing any data?

Best way to do this, use PK chunking with Bulk API.

Refer [Walk Through a Bulk Query Sample Using PK Chunking](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_curl_walkthrough_pk_chunking.htm)

Comment: +1 for capturing the milliseconds.